# Keras can not recognize the optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I implemented a Keras model using eager execution. When I run *model.fit* function in the last line of code, I get this error:

```
compile() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'AE_optimizer' and 'classification_optimizer'
```

I can not figure out the reason for the error. Why the optimizer is not recognized by the Keras API?

Here is the source code that I am using.
I use a class and define two components for the model: the encoder and projection head. I use contrastive learning to train the encoder. For this purpose, I have a contrastive loss inside the class. The compiler function has the tracker and the optimizer, but it raises the error. In *train_step* function, I use two augmented version of the input (x) and then I pass them through the projection head network for calculating the contrastive loss.

Keras does not start to train, it shows the error in the last line *pretraining_model.fit()* function.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
# Define the contrastive model with model-subclassing
class ContrastiveModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.temperature = 1.0
        
        self.encoder = keras.Sequential(
        [
            keras.Input(shape=(42,)),
            layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
            layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
        ],
        name="encoder",
    )
        # Non-linear MLP as projection head
        self.projection_head = keras.Sequential(
            [
                keras.Input(shape=(20,)),
                layers.Dense(20, activation="relu"),
                layers.Dense(20),
            ],
            name="projection_head",
        )
        

    def compile(self, contrastive_optimizer, **kwargs):
        super().compile(**kwargs)

        self.contrastive_optimizer = contrastive_optimizer
        
        # self.contrastive_loss will be defined as a method
        

        self.contrastive_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="c_loss")
        self.contrastive_accuracy = keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='c_accuracy')#SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="c_acc")
        
  

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.contrastive_loss_tracker,
            self.contrastive_accuracy,
        ]

    def contrastive_loss(self, projections_1, projections_2):
        # InfoNCE loss (information noise-contrastive estimation)
        # NT-Xent loss (normalized temperature-scaled cross entropy)

        # Cosine similarity: the dot product of the l2-normalized feature vectors
        projections_1 = tf.math.l2_normalize(projections_1, axis=1)
        projections_2 = tf.math.l2_normalize(projections_2, axis=1)
        similarities = (
            tf.matmul(projections_1, projections_2, transpose_b=True) / self.temperature
        )

        # The similarity between the representations of two augmented views of the
        # same image should be higher than their similarity with other views
        batch_size = tf.shape(projections_1)[0]
        contrastive_labels = tf.range(batch_size)
        self.contrastive_accuracy.update_state(contrastive_labels, similarities)
        self.contrastive_accuracy.update_state(
            contrastive_labels, tf.transpose(similarities)
        )

        # The temperature-scaled similarities are used as logits for cross-entropy
        # a symmetrized version of the loss is used here
        loss_1_2 = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
            contrastive_labels, similarities, from_logits=True
        )
        loss_2_1 = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
            contrastive_labels, tf.transpose(similarities), from_logits=True
        )
        return (loss_1_2 + loss_2_1) / 2

    def train_step(self, data):
        # Both labeled and unlabeled images are used, without labels
        masks1, augmented1 = augmentation(d1,data)


        masks2, augmented2 = augmentation(d2,data)


        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            features_1 = self.encoder(augmented1, training=True)
            features_2 = self.encoder(augmented2, training=True)
            
            # The representations are passed through a projection mlp
            projections_1 = self.projection_head(features_1, training=True)
            projections_2 = self.projection_head(features_2, training=True)
            closs = self.contrastive_loss(projections_1, projections_2)          
            
            total_loss = closs 

        trainable_var =  self.encoder.trainable_weights + self.projection_head.trainable_weights 
        gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, trainable_var,)
        self.contrastive_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_var,))
        self.contrastive_loss_tracker.update_state(closs)
             
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

# Contrastive pretraining
pretraining_model = ContrastiveModel()
pretraining_model.compile(contrastive_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),)

pretraining_history = pretraining_model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=25)
```

Can you guide me on why this error is happening?

Comment: Not sure about the error message, but in general it looks like you're trying some mixture between Keras mode (using `model.compile()`, `model.fit()`) and eager execution (using `tf.GradientTape()` etc.). If you're using eager execution there's no need to use `compile()` and `fit()`. Have a look here for basic differences between the two: https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-2-1-a-how-to-a3e6400d0899

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did not solve the problem. But I could learn the pure eager execution without mixing the modes. The problem was importing the TensorFlow two times. In the code, I import augmentation function from another file. In the other file, I import TensorFlow again. The second import is disabling the eager mode execution.